# not able to install node modules and build below react app

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, create-react-app

```
 {
   "name": "sample-react",
   "description": "Sample Website",
   "version": "2.0.0",
   "keywords": [
     "xxxx",
   ],
   "repository": {
     "type": "git"
   },
   "scripts": {
     "start": "react-scripts start",
     "build": "react-scripts build",
     "test": "react-scripts test",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject",
     "watch": "cra-build-watch --verbose -p /"
   },
   "dependencies": {
     "@okta/okta-auth-js": "^5.5.0",
     "axios": "^0.21.0",
     "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
     "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.12",
     "classnames": "^2.2.6",
     "connected-react-router": "^6.5.2",
     "core-js": "^3.8.1",
     "date-fns": "^2.4.1",
     "debounce-promise": "^3.1.2",
     "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
     "formik": "^2.2.6",
     "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
     "jquery": "^3.5.1",
     "lodash": "^4.17.15",
     "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
     "luxon": "^1.25.0",
     "match-sorter": "^4.0.1",
     "moment": "^2.24.0",
     "numeral": "^2.0.6",
     "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
     "qs": "^6.9.4",
     "react": "^16.13.0",
     "react-app-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
     "react-block-ui": "^1.3.1",
     "react-bootstrap": "^0.33.1",
     "react-datepicker": "^2.9.6",
     "react-dnd": "^9.4.0",
     "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^9.4.0",
     "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
     "react-file-download": "^0.3.5",
     "react-input-mask": "2.0.4",
     "react-number-format": "^4.4.4",
     "react-overlays": "^1.2.0",
     "react-paginate": "^6.3.0",
     "react-redux": "^7.1.1",
     "react-redux-toastr": "^7.5.1",
     "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.25.0",
     "react-router-dom": "^5.1.0",
     "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
     "react-select": "^3.1.1",
     "react-table": "^6.10.3",
     "react-table-6": "^6.11.0",
     "reactabular-column-extensions": "^8.9.3",
     "reactabular-dnd": "^8.16.0",
     "reactabular-table": "^8.14.0",
     "redux": "^4.0.4",
     "redux-form": "^8.2.6",
     "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
     "sortabular": "^1.6.0",
     "table-resolver": "^4.1.1",
     "use-latest": "^1.2.0",
     "validatorjs": "^3.17.1",
     "yup": "^0.32.8"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
     "cra-build-watch": "^3.2.0"
   },
   "eslintConfig": {
     "extends": "react-app"
   },
   "browserslist": {
     "production": [
       ">0.2%",
       "not dead",
       "not op_mini all"
     ],
     "development": [
       "ie 11",
       "last 1 chrome version",
       "last 1 firefox version",
       "last 1 safari version"
     ]
   }
 }
```

First I am getting below error,

```
unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! Found: react-dnd@9.5.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dnd
npm ERR!   react-dnd@"^9.4.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-dnd@">= 2.0.0 < 3.0.0" from reactabular-dnd@8.16.0
```

below are the packages I am using,

```
"reactabular-dnd": "^8.16.0",
"react-dnd": "^9.4.0",
```

tried both with legacy peer deps npm install successful but getting into another issue if i run npm run build

[image]

Comment: Whats your node js version?

Answer (score 1):

This error mostly codes with using  non-LTS version of node.

Install the latest lts version from https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/

Comment: Yes @Ian Andwati. you are correct. If i uninstall node v18.13 and install 14.21 i am able to install sucessfully even though it still warns me saying 'npm WARN reactabular-dnd@8.16.0 requires a peer of react-dnd@>= 2.0.0 < 3.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.'

Comment: What is best way to handle this and update node to latest LTS?

Comment: Check out node version manager(nvm) https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm . Although its for mac and linux you can use it in WSL. There is also this that supports windows https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows